# $.getJSON() function isn't responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I've been trying to figure this thing out for a while now.
The *users.json* file I'm using is located in "JSON" folder right next  to the rest of the files. `alert("Before")` is working but I can't get the `alert("After")` to work :/

If anyone could help me I'd be grateful for life.

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(readJSONFile);

function readJSONFile() {
    alert("Before");
    $.getJSON("JSON/users.json", function(data){
        alert("After");
        let options ='';
        for(let i= 0; i<data.length;i++){
            options += `<option value="${data[i].firstName}">${data[i].firstName}</option>`;
        }
        $('#users').html(options);
    });
}
```

**users.json**

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address": "Del Mar"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jonah",
        "lastName": "Hill",
        "address": "Jerusalem"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Bond",
        "address": "San Jose"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in your console? (F12 in your browser)

Comment: And while you are there look in network tab and inspect the actual request

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/.../JSON/users.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Well then @MitchTal there is your answer.  You need to just solve the cors issue.  I would say to just try a local path and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just left off a ./ to indicate that the path is relative to the current path.

```
$.getJSON("./JSON/users.json", function(data){
```